# laptop make sparking or ticking kind of sound in photohsop

Tags: windows, laptop, dell-inspiron

I have DELL N-Series core i7 laptop & when I am working in photoshop, specifically in large PSD Files, when I use arrow keys to move the object around, or even click sometime on objects, I hear a weird spark like sound from laptop, I only felt it when I work in photoshop, & nothing else.

I am not finding any help, can anyone guess what & why this is ?

Comment: Could you expound on Dell N series i7? I'd prefer not to google specs on your pc, but if you are using PS and very large files, with many layers, it could be a memory problem. Also keep in mind when you use power driven applications like PS you have to save often so that your work doesn't pile up in RAM. Do you power off your pc or leave it on all the time? High demand for memory and keeping the computer on can make your pc get bogged down -- so with minimum details given for me to ponder, "thrashing" comes to mind...

Answer (score 0):

That sound is from your Laptop Hard Drive. It's working overtime to deliver you the data.

I'd recommend you do a scan for bad sectors too-

Go to start menu, type "cmd" without the quotation marks.

Right click it and click "Run as Adminstrator"

then type "chkdsk" without the quotations. It will show any bad sectors in your HDD.

Or else do a scan following these procedures-

> 1. Right click the Start Windows icon.
> 2. In the shortcut menu, click Open Windows Explorer.
> 3. In the navigation pane, click Computer so that your drives appear in the right pane.
> 4. Right-click the drive that you want to check.
> 5. Click Properties.
> 6. Click the Tools tab.
> 7. Click the Check now button.
> 8. In the Check Disk  window, select the Automatically fix file system errors check box.
>
> Note  If you want to perform a detailed test of the hard drive, you
>   can select the Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors check box.
>   You should do that in the justified suspicion of existing hardware
>   error in any case. But please note that the operation can then take a
>   long time. For a first routine check, we recommend that you do not
>   select this option.
>
> 9. Click Start.
> 10. If the drive that you want to check is currently in use and it is your system drive, you will see a dialog box with a warning message.
>       In this case, click Schedule disk check.
> 11. Exit all open programs, and then restart your computer. The checking will start automatically before next Windows startup and
>       display the results when completed.
> 12. If you are not checking the system drive, you do not have to turn off the computer. However, the selected drive may also be in use. In
>       this case, you receive a message. After you have saved all files and
>       close all open programs, click Force a dismount.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2641432)

Answer (score 0):

It is called HDD Head Parking. It is explained well here: http://disablehddapm.blogspot.com/2011/12/disabling-hard-disk-drive-advanced.html

There is a tool listed in the same link, you can download and install it. I myself personally used it and the sound heard less frequent after using the tool.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I've had this problem in the past, nice to know this is available.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of specific characters like bullets, dots etc. in the layer names. You can test renaming those layers and see if the problem gets fixed.

It might also be an issue with the 'generator' feature in photoshop.

More details about similar issue with beeping sound in photoshop is discussed and resolved in below link -
https://forums.adobe.com/message/5849242

Hope it helps.